# CDI events: Transactional observer called BEFORE_COMPLETION causes INSERT statements to be executed twice

Tags: jpa, cdi, payara, java-ee-8

I'm having problems with transactional CDI events. I want to perform some operations at the end of a transaction, before the commit. Currently I'm using transactional CDI events for this.

Here ist the code that saves an entity (or gets it, if it's already present):

```
@Override
public MyEntity getOrSave(MyEntity il) {
    return fetchByName(il.getName()).orElseGet(() -> {
        getEm().persist(il);
        getEm().flush();
        return il;
    });
}
```

Later an event is triggered that should perform an update of a table:

```
softwareRelatedActionPerformedEvent.fire(new SoftwareRelatedActionPerformedEvent(softwareId));
```

An observer listens to these events:

```
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public class UpdateSoftwareReadModelObserver {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UpdateSoftwareReadModelObserver.class);

    @Inject
    private SoftwareSearchViewDAO softwareSearchViewDAO;

    public void onSoftwareChange(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.BEFORE_COMPLETION)
                                 @Nonnull final SoftwareRelatedActionPerformedEvent event) {
        LOG.debug("UPDATE OBS START000");
        final List<SoftwareSearchView> softwareSearchViews
            = softwareSearchViewDAO.fetchSoftwareSearchViewById(event.getSoftwareId());
        LOG.debug("UPDATE OBS END000");
    }
}
```

The DAO simply fetches some data:

```
@Inject
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Nonnull
@Override
public List<SoftwareSearchView> fetchSoftwareSearchViewById(@Nonnull Long softwareId) {
    return new JPAQuery<SoftwareSearchView>(entityManager).from(softwareSearchView)
        .where(softwareSearchView.softwareSearchId.id.eq(softwareId))
        .fetch();
}
```

Now the confusing part is that in the log I can see that the INSERT statement for `MyEntity` is executed twice, which causes a duplicate entry exception:

```
[2021-09-08T06:04:53.493+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093493] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.493--UnitOfWork(660360545)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--begin unit of work flush
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.494+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093494] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.494--ClientSession(1676448281)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--TX beginTransaction, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.494+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093494] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Fine]: sql: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.494--ClientSession(1676448281)--Connection(1328559837)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--INSERT INTO swhrl.myentity (name) VALUES (?)
    bind => [I020-21-07-200]
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.495+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093495] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Fine]: sql: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.495--ClientSession(1676448281)--Connection(1328559837)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--select lastval()
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.496+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093496] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.496--UnitOfWork(660360545)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--end unit of work flush
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.496+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093496] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.496--UnitOfWork(660360545)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--resume unit of work
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.500+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093500] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.5--UnitOfWork(660360545)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--TX beforeCompletion callback, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.501+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093501] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.501--UnitOfWork(660360545)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--begin unit of work commit
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.503+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [FINE] [] [com.bmw.swhrl.kcmgmt.observer.UpdateSoftwareReadModelObserver] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093503] [levelValue: 500] [CLASSNAME: com.bmw.swhrl.kcmgmt.observer.UpdateSoftwareReadModelObserver] [METHODNAME: onSoftwareChange] [[
  UPDATE OBS START000]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.505+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093505] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.505--UnitOfWork(660360545)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--begin unit of work flush
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.505+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093505] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.505--ClientSession(1676448281)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--TX beginTransaction, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.505+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093505] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Fine]: sql: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.505--ClientSession(1676448281)--Connection(148360781)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--INSERT INTO swhrl.myentity (name) VALUES (?)
    bind => [I020-21-07-200]
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.511+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093511] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Fine]: sql: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.511--ClientSession(1676448281)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--SELECT 1
]]

[2021-09-08T06:04:53.516+0000] [Payara 5.23.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=85 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1631081093516] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Warning]: 2021-09-08 06:04:53.514--UnitOfWork(660360545)--Thread(Thread[http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4),5,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.payara-p3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myentity_name_key"
  Detail: Key (name)=(I020-21-07-200) already exists.
```

The first INSERT statement is executed when `persist()` is called. The second one when `fetch()` is called in `fetchSoftwareSearchViewById()`.

You can also see that the observer is called during the `beforeCompletion` phase of the transaction.

Everything works when I comment out the database query in `fetchSoftwareSearchViewById()`, so executing this query somehow causes the INSERT statement to be executed again. I've checked the `EntityManager` instances used in `getOrSave()` and `fetchSoftwareSearchViewById()`, both are the same instances.

I have no idea what is going on here...

I'm using JDK 11 and Payara 5.23.

Comment: `MyEntity.name` is not the primary key/JPA ID, just a field with a unique constraint right? Also, have you tried removing the `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)` from the observer - it will run in the same transaction anyway.